# How to cache home webpage for PWA

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to cache the homepage for PWA I have the necessary files to cache:

```
var filesToCache = [
    '/',
    '/css/app.css',
    '/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    '/img/offline_icon.png',
    '/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    '/js/app.js',
    '/apple-touch-icon.png',
    '/css/style.min.css',
    '/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
    '/css/templates/themify-icons.css',
    '/site.webmanifest',
    '/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js',
    '/js/pooper.min.js',
    '/js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js',
    '/js/inspinia.js',
    '/js/plugins/nouislider/nouislider.js',
    '/js/plugins/sweetalert/sweetalert.js',
    '/js/plugins/pace/pace.min.js',
    '/js/app.js?id=a55c52df98f58afc1dc5',
    '/favicon-32x32.png',
    '/favicon-16x16.png',
    '/android-chrome-192x192.png',
    '/android-chrome-512x512.png',
    '/css/templates/aqua-kana-font.css',
    // Here will go the resources to cache
];
```

this is the cache on the install

```
// Cache on install
self.addEventListener("install", event => {
    this.skipWaiting();
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(staticCacheName)
            .then(cache => {
                return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
            })
    )
```

and the serve

```
// Serve from Cache
self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
            .then(response => {
                return response || fetch(event.request);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                return caches.match('/');
            })
    )
});
```

If I change the "/" for "/offline" URI it works correctly, but I have to change the cached "offline" view to the home view for use the web page without connection (only home)

this is the problem with the homepage cache: (status: cancelled, type: fetch, initiator: servicebrocker.js)

[image]